# How to calculate temperature change of a decompressing gas canister?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, rocket-science, gas

I am currently trying to find the temperature drop of a decompressing gas canister for rocketry club to make sure that it doesn't get too cold to affect nearby components like electronics.

The canister starts out at 6000 psi, and drops to 1000 psi by the end as the helium inside is used up as pressurant for another tank. The volume of the tank stays constant at 10 gallons.

Is this enough conditions to solve the problems? Are there other data that I need to gather to solve this problem? Finally, what formulas would I use to find the temperature drop of this decompressing gas?

Comment: What is your understanding so far of what needs to be. done?  What level of thermodynamics course have you had so far?

Comment: Well I am guessing that this is a control volume problem (since constant volume). At first I did this with ideal gas law but then I realized that doesn't make sense since the helium is being drained out over time.

Comment: Would you feel you needed proof if I told you that the entropy per unit mass of the gas remaining in the tank at any time is constant?  If not, do you know how to determine the change in entropy with specific volume for a non-ideal gas?